# Seriously debugging node.js 'Cannot find module xyz/abcd'

Tags: node.js, module, require

I have the `Error: Cannot find module xyz/abcd` error.

YES, the required module is installed.

According to the pseudo-code of module.require [here](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together), it *should* work.

I tried to dive inside `require()` to understand why it can't find my file. My node debugger won't step into require(). I've tried the `strace / grep NOENT` technique whithout success either.

Any idea how to troubleshoot a nasty `require()` failure ?

Note : just in case : the error comes from a file node_modules/xyz/a requiring xyz/b. It should work according to the doc.

Comment: Is this your own module? How did you install it?

Comment: @nhaa I didn't want to dive into the details since it's complicated, but it's my own module A which is a dependency of another own module B. `npm ls` summarize it as [root] -> B (extraneous) -> A (npm link). Inside A are 3 files x, y and z and A/x require A/y and A/z. A works standalone in A unit test but not when a dependency of B in B unit tests. Anyway it should work according to require pseudocode.

Comment: I see there are `debug(...)` calls in node.js code. Anyone know how to activate them ?

Comment: `$ NODE_DEBUG=relevant_module_name node index.js`

Comment: I got this problem after upgrading from node v0.10 to version 0.12.2 and I realized I essentially uninstalled all node packages.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

By investigating more, I think I found a good technique :

```
export NODE_DEBUG=module
node my_script.js
```

gives such interesting traces :

```
looking for "/(...)/tests_init.js" in ["/home/(me)/.nave/installed/0.10.24/lib/node","/home/(me)/.node_modules","/home/(me)/.node_libraries","/home/(me)/.nave/installed/0.10.24/lib/node"]
```

And BTW, it shows that node is **not searching at all where I thought it was**. Time to investigate...

---

[edit] end of the story :

1) it appears that node is not treating well modules installed with `npm link`. `require(...)` sometimes fails to select files from inside a npm-linked module. I have no desire to investigate further the exact error conditions, I'll just conclude that `npm link` is very brittle.

2) beware of node looking for node_modules all the way into the parent dirs of current working directory ! I found that modules from parent folders of my app where sometime selected !

Comment: I wish this was the first result! I had this issue and all the other 'debug' questions are just npm install answers. Yours actually shows how to debug! You fixed my issue in about 90 seconds.

Comment: Is export a node command or a commandlet? Where do i put this code.

Comment: @Ernesto "export" is a bash command. The 1st block is supposed to be a bash terminal where you are typing commands. https://ss64.com/bash/export.html